# Retrieve Year in Mysql's Store Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

> I want to count no of id each year.
>
> My table schame :-  id number , s_date date
>
> And data

-----+-----------

| id  | s_date     |

+-----+------------+

| 1  | 2013-10-15 |

| 10 | 2013-10-27 |

| 11 | 2013-10-27 |

| 12 | 2013-10-27 |

| 13 | 2013-01-27 |

| 14 | 2013-11-11 |

| 15 | 2013-11-10 |

| 16 | 2012-11-10 |

| 17 | 2013-01-10 |

| 18 | 2012-10-27 |

| 2  | 2013-10-16 |

| 3  | 2013-10-16 |

| 4  | 2013-10-16 |

| 5  | 2013-10-17 |

| 6  | 2013-10-17 |

| 7  | 2013-10-17 |

| 8  | 2013-10-18 |

| 9  | 2013-10-26 |

> And I want to O/p like

+-----------+--------------+

| tot        | year1        |

+-----------+--------------+

|         2  |         2012 |

|        16 |         2013 |

+-----------+--------------+

> And My Store Procedure :-

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE sen49()

```
-> begin

-> declare year1 datetime;

-> declare tot INT;

-> select count(id) INTO tot,year(s_date) INTO year1 from year_info group by year(s_date);

-> end $$
```

Error:-

ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: year

So please help me to solve this error.... year declaration I try date and varchar data type...but not solved this error.

Comment: Why are we using a sproc?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code -

```
BEGIN
  SELECT YEAR(s_date) year, COUNT(*) count FROM year_info GROUP BY YEAR(s_date);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUBSTRING(s_date, 1, 4) AS Year
FROM table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(s_date, 1, 4)
```

MySQL can treat date fields as "strings" if you want and stores them in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD)